# a bytes-like object is required, not str

Tags: python-3.8

My code:

```
from subprocess import*
import time
p = Popen([r'E:\Hacking\Kien_mannowar\Vulnerabilities\sample(1)\sample\VULNERABLE_o_NO.exe','f'],stdout=PIPE,stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
 
print ("Attach to the debugger and press Enter\n")
input()
 
size="10\n"
p.stdin.write(size)
 
time.sleep(0.5)
 
user_input="AAAA\n"
p.stdin.write(user_input)
 
testresult = p.communicate()[0]
time.sleep(0.5)
print(testresult)
print (size)
print (user_input)
```

Comment: How do I solve this problem?

Comment: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: The answer to your question is:  size = bytes("10\n", "utf-8")

A suggestion. When you ask a question, make sure you narrow down the problem to the minimum number of lines that it takes to reproduce the error. In this case, all it takes is a popen to some file, and calling write on it. Everything else is superfluous.